# How to extract .tiff images of different sizes

Tags: qgis, wms

I have some WMS maps that I need to export. They need to be roughly 1m resolution and the pixel count needs to be divisible evenly by 32. I can export them using "save as..."

[image]

but when exported the files come out as multiple -I can work with multiple- 2000px x 2000px at a 1 meter resolution.(Half way there).

[image]

Is there any way to set the export pixel count per tiff file?

Edit: There is only the wms. I tried the other way and the service I am using only offers wms.

Comment: What server software is providing the WMS layers?  Do you know if there is an accompanying WCS for the data?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. The way to do this is in a bug that they have. you have to click a few times on the "create VRT file" button a few times and then in the settings will pop up a editing area for the file sizes.